# Laravel - Automatically log out other laravel apps through laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I plan on creating multiple laravel apps that will interact with each other. These apps will have their own databases however, they will all use the same 'user' table in separate database. I am planning to pass a user-specific UUID through the URL so that the user will be automatically logged-in to different apps once they access it.

Given that, is there a way to logout the user's multiple Auth sessions in other laravel apps once he logouts from one of them?

Comment: no. you will use APIs and/or localstorage for this